# Why am I encouraged to put my main Node.js script in a folder called "bin"?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm using the application generator provided by the Express framework for Node.js. One thing it creates is a main file named "www" that is placed in a folder named "bin." I usually associate "bin" with binary executables so I'm wondering what the thinking is behind that decision. I'm assuming that the point is to take advantage of rules or conventions for permissions that may or may not already exist on your system for directories that contain executables, even though it's a plain text/JavaScript file and not a binary. Can anyone confirm or disconfirm that?

Comment: It just distinguishes the runnable application file from the non-runnable library files. `bin` doesn't imply "binary" in the sense you're thinking; you'll find plenty of Perl and Python in `bin` dirs as well.

Comment: Yes, I noticed that. But it does originally come from "binary", right?

Comment: Yes, its original purpose was for binaries following compilation. It's a system/OS convention, most commonly with Unix/Linux, which expended in use to include any "*executable*."

Comment: Yes, it does. Unix tends to call programs "binaries" even when they're not particularly binary. It also calls the executable memory image of a program the "text" even though it's definitely not text :)

Comment: Maybe the reason is historically, but now a days executables are not all binaries. For example have a look at the content of `/usr/local/bin/npm`. You will find a node.js script. This link gives a good description of what the /usr/bin directory is for http://www.linfo.org/usr_bin.html. "contains most of the executable files (i.e., ready-to-run programs)"